# Custom payment Method: Billing Address

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have this custom payment method:

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>

    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine but it does not show the billing address selector, see red square below from other payment method:

[image]

Any clue on why this is happening?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok just found the problem.... On my checkout_index_index.xml I was misisng this( see code bewtween **):

```
  <item name="PagamentoTransferenciaBancaria" xsi:type="array">
 <item name="component" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/js/view/payment/pagamentotransferenciabancaria-renderer</item>
 <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
 **
     <item name="PagamentoTransferenciaBancaria" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>**
 </item>
 </item>
```

Comment: can you add full code?